# how to read .R file as a string or how to extract comments (# lines) from the R code

Tags: r

I want to extract comments from a source file. all the lines which are starting with # character mention in a .R file

Comment: [`readLines`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/readLines.html) and [`grep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html), perhaps as `grep("^\\s*#", readLines(somefile), value=TRUE)`. This won't find comments after code (e.g., `list(1:5) # list of numbers`).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's my comment as an answer. Using a source file like this as `arbabnasir.R`:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725155/how-to-read-r-file-as-a-string-or-how-to-extract-comments-lines-from-the-r
# some additional comments
myfunc <- function(a, ...) {
  # verify input parameters
  stopifnot(is.integer(a)) # something here
  cat("# hello\n")
  # add one
  a+1L
}
```

I can parse it this way to see just the comments:

```
grep("^\\s*#", readLines("~/StackOverflow/arbabnasir.R"), value=TRUE)
# [1] "# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725155/how-to-read-r-file-as-a-string-or-how-to-extract-comments-lines-from-the-r"
# [2] "# some additional comments"                                                                                               
# [3] "  # verify input parameters"                                                                                              
# [4] "  # add one"
```

If you need everything *except* whole-line comments:

```
grep("^\\s*#", readLines("~/StackOverflow/arbabnasir.R"), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
# [1] "myfunc <- function(a, ...) {"               
# [2] "  stopifnot(is.integer(a)) # something here"
# [3] "  cat(\"# hello\\n\")"                      
# [4] "  a+1L"                                     
# [5] "}"                                          
# [6] ""
```

Note that the `... # something here` comment was *not* included in the list of comments, as there is "something" before the comment character. If you try to extract them lazily, you could run into problems as shown with my `cat(" hello\n")` line of code: the comment character is in a string so is not really a comment character. This stops being an efficient regex problem and gets into source tokenization and contextual interpretation, well outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Though not part of the question, if you need to remove the empty strings you can use `Filter(nzchar, grep(...))`.